# Why doesn't my UPDATE query work? MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm working on a blog website and i'm currently stuck at making a blog edit page. For some reason my blog UPDATE query doesn't work, and i can't figure out why it isn't working. I'm not getting an error. It is just not updating anything.

I'm collecting the data from an old blog and inserting it into my form. And then I'm trying to update it using my update query.

This is my code so far:

**aanpassen.php**

```
    <?php

    $error=false;
    include_once('includes/connection.php');
    include_once('includes/article.php');

    $article = new Article;


    if ( isset( $_POST ['id'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['content'] ) ) {

        $id = $_POST ['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = nl2br( $_POST['content'] );

        if (empty($title) || empty($content) || empty($id)){

            $error='All fields are required!';

        } else {
$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE articles SET article_title = :title, 
                        article_content = :content WHERE id=:id");
            if( $query ){
$id = $_POST ['id'];
$query->bindValue(':title', $title);
$query->bindValue(':content', $content);
$query->bindValue(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
                header( sprintf( 'Location: index.php?status=%s', $result ? 'ok' : 'failed' ) );
            } else {
                exit('bad foo - unable to prepare sql query');
            }
        }
    }

    if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $data = $article->fetch_data( $id );
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }

?>

<form action="aanpassen.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="title" class="titleform" placeholder="Blog naam" value="<?php echo $data['article_title']; ?>" />
    <textarea name="content" id="summernote" rows="15" cols="50"><?php echo $data['article_content'] ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="buttonclass" value="Aanmaken" />
</form>
<?php
if ($error)
    printf('<h1>%s</h1>', $error);
?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php 
try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms', 'root', 'root');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('Database error.');
}
?>
```

Comment: You first argument for `bindValue()` should have `:` at the beginning like - `:title`

Comment: You do not check for any errors after calling the execute() method, so you cannot possibly know if the sql statement executed correctly.

Comment: you should not use or in the if, it's || in php.

Comment: @Wils Did that. Still doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: @KarloKokkak Tried that. Still doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: Can you add some `echo` or `var_dump` to your code and remove the redirection just to check if you get the right data when you need them?

Comment: And maybe try to remove the `action="aanpassen.php"` in your form and just write `action=""`if you do your update in the same page where the form is

Comment: That code is from aanpassen.php?

Comment: @KarloKokkak Yes.

Comment: Can you update the posted code?

Comment: Can you post the code of connection.php?

Comment: @KarloKokkak Updated and posted.

Comment: Made an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

you missed ":" in all the bindValue arguments. should be like this:

`$query->bindValue(':title', $title);
$query->bindValue(':content', $content);
$query->bindValue(':id', $id);`

and also `if (empty($title) or empty($content) or empty($id))` this should be `if (empty($title) || empty($content) || empty($id))` like this

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me sadly.

Comment: Still doesn't do anything for me. It just sends me to the index.html whenever i click the submit button.

Comment: header(sprintf('Location: index.php?status=%s', $result ? 'ok' : 'failed' )); it is sending you to the index.php because of this.  what are getting after status= in your address bar?

Comment: Do you mean this? "aanpassen.php?id=33"

Comment: no as you mentioned in your previous comment that it is redirecting you to index.php  everytime you submit form. so are you getting any argumrny after index.php  after submitting form?

Comment: No, i'm not getting an argument.

Comment: if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $data = $article->fetch_data( $id );
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    } can you comment this code and try it again??

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't do anything for me yet.

Comment: what are you getting in $result you used it in if statement but doesn't stores anything in $result??

Comment: $query->execute(); should be like this $result = $query->execute();

Comment: I changed it into: $result = $query->execute(); But is still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you access aanpassen.php initially it's in this format right - aanpassen.php?id=1??

Otherwise your code seems fine when I tested it.

**Just Change:**

```
$query->execute();
header( sprintf( 'Location: index.php?status=%s', $result ? 'ok' : 'failed' ) );
```

**To:**

```
$success = $query->execute();
header( 'Location: index.php?status='.( $success ? 'ok' : 'failed' ) );exit();
```

Comment: Yeah when i access the page ' aanpassen.php?id=1 '  is the url.